# Unable to initialize module - gRPC installed in Xamp when running PHP project

Tags: php, laravel, windows, xampp, grpc

I tried to install gRPC on my Xampp server ( [I follow this steps to install](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php)). I downloaded the gRPC 1.43.0 (PHP 8.1 Thread Safe (TS) x64).
My current PHP project running on PHP 8.2.0(CLI). When I run my PHP project after the installation, the error is as shown in the picture attached. Any reply highly appreciated. Thank you.
[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lntk1.png)
I did try to restart my apache service, and try another DLL version but no luck. Error persist.
I expect the gRPC enabled and seen in my PHPInfo page.

Answer (score -1):

please see [this](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#c-implementation) and [this](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-the-php-grpc-extension/) i think it's going to help you to solve your problem